# 2 sshd configurations 1 for internal and 1 external

Tags: ssh, sshd

How can I setup open ssh server so that if i'm ssh'ng from a local lan I want it to be via port 22 but if I'm coming externally its via port 12345 for example.

Then for external access I'd like some different (stricter) rules in sshd_config

Comment: Please add more details on your network topology. How does the system connect to the outside? does it have more than one network interface? will external connections come from a router and, if so, how does the router handle or translate external connections? (maybe via NAT). Or is routing handled by the server itself, maybe using iptables?

Comment: It works on 18.04

Comment: Zeke's answer below worked for me on 18.04. Regarding your external sshd, you can limit users with the AllowUsers option. How strict do you want? Create a user with a password for a username: eR4d092a. Jail him. Limit him to a couple of commands. Require he "su" out to get into your system. Alias the "su" command. For example, "su" becomes "alberny." Make eR4d092a's password 14 to 16 characters. Limit external access only to eR4d092a: AllowUsers eR4d092a  No one will ever guess a username-password combination set up this way on a non-standard port.

Answer (score 11):

[Eric Carvalho](https://askubuntu.com/users/65926/eric-carvalho)'s answer works for pre 15.04 but they deprecated and then removed upstart from Ubuntu, [SystemdForUpstartUsers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers).

These steps have been adapted to work with systemd.

1. Copy the SSH configuration file:

   `sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_external`
2. Copy the systemd configuration file:

   `sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service /lib/systemd/system/sshd-external.service`

   in the new file (`/lib/systemd/system/sshd-external.service`) change the line:

   `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS`

   to:

   `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_external`

   and the line:

   `Alias=sshd.service`

   to:

   `Alias=sshd-external.service`
3. Now customize `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_external` to your needs (e.g. change `Port 22` to `Port 12345`)
4. enable the service

   <strike>`sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/ssh-external.service /etc/systemd/system/sshd-external.service`</strike>

   If you have run the above command then run `sudo systemctl disable sshd-external.service` before running the next command

   `sudo systemctl enable sshd-external.service`

   `sudo service sshd-external start`

This has been tested on Ubuntu 16.04 on real hardware and a virtual machine in virtualbox.

Let me know if this doesn't work. I've been known to make typos.

Comment: It works on 18.04

Comment: It seems that sshd-external will use pam_unix() auhentication, and I had to create /etc/pam.d/sshd-external to configure non default pam.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 - You just need to use: sudo systemctl start sshd-external to start the second instance. service sshd-external start - may be a typo

Answer (score 3):

Create another SSH service instance.

1. Copy the SSH configuration file:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_external
   ```
2. Copy the upstart configuration file:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/init/ssh.conf /etc/init/ssh-external.conf
   ```

   In the new file (`ssh-external.conf`), change the line:

   ```
   mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd
   ```

   to:

   ```
   mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd-external
   ```

   And change the line:

   ```
   exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D
   ```

   to:

   ```
   exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_external
   ```
3. Create the link to upstart:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job /etc/init.d/ssh-external
   ```

Now customize `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_external` to your needs (e.g. change `Port 22` to `Port 12345`) and start the service:

```
sudo service ssh-external start
```