# Possible? OpenSSL server listens on 2 ports, but only one with 2-factor authentications

Tags: ssh

I have setup openssh to listen to 2 ports on my server. One for internal access, the other for remote access over the internet. For the latter, I’d like to employ 2-factor authentications. But don’t want the same for access from inside the home network. Is this possible?

Thanks much for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

It actually  appears as though this will require two completely separate ssh daemons to make it work rather than adding an additional port to the current ssh daemon.  Detailed instructions are here: [2 sshd configurations 1 for internal and 1 external](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324503/2-sshd-configurations-1-for-internal-and-1-external/865804#865804)
.  The basic premise seems to be copying the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and the systemd config file as well.  Then setting up the copied systemd file to use the new sshd_config file.